# Is there anyway I could detect the height and the width of particular color in an image?

Tags: php, gd

I'm using PHP's GD library to mess around with image manipulation a little bit. I have this image of the twitter logo (the lowercase "t"). The background is white and the t is a light blue. Is there any way that I could use the the gd library to find out the width and the height of the twitter "t"?

Thanks,

Lance

Comment: Exact color, or fuzzy color selection?  (Keep in mind JPEG will throw you off, if you are looking for exact color matching.)  Just one instance, or of every matching instance of something that color?

Comment: Crawl the image pixel by pixel, although that would probably take ages.

Comment: Both exact color and fuzzy color. Every instance of something matching that color,

Comment: On a sidenote, have a look at: [How do I ask questions here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) especially the last sentence.